# Nginx pass my request to default or local address

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

There is two issue with NGINX configurations.
I tried to setup [*prestashop*](https://www.prestashop.com/en) on *CentOS 7* with *Nginx* according to [this instrument](https://websiteforstudents.com/install-prestashop-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-with-nginx-mariadb-php-7-1-and-lets-encrypt-free-ssl-tls/) that I found similar this in Prestashop forums . the     nginx.config file is as below:

```
    user nginx;
    worker_processes auto;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    pid /run/nginx.pid;
    events {
        worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
  client_header_timeout 300;
  client_body_timeout 300;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
  client_max_body_size 32m;
  fastcgi_buffers 8 128k;
  fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
  map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
      default upgrade;
      ''      close;
    }
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   6500;
    types_hash_max_size 3048;
    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include nginx-prestashop.conf;
}
```

and nginx-prestashop.conf file is:

```
upstream php-fpm {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000; #unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
}
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    root /var/www/html/prestashop;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    server_name_in_redirect off;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    location / {
    rewrite ^/api/?(.*)$ /webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$     /img/p/$1/$1$2.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$     /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-    9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/c/([0-9]+)(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/c/([a-zA-Z-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9]+)(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;        
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files  $uri =404;
    fastcgi_index            index.php;
    fastcgi_pass             php-fpm;
    include                  fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:443;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  server_tokens off; 
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  server_name_in_redirect off;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/sslnginx.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/sslnginx.key;
  ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-    SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_timeout 5m;
  location / {
     proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:80/ $scheme://$host:443/;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
 }
 location ~ /\.ht {
     deny all;
 }
}
```

when I tried *http://www.example.com* it redirects me to *localhost/index.phph?* and when I tried *https://www.example.com/* it took me to NGINX default page which locates in */usr/share/nginx/html/* and when I tried insight of server,  I encountered *Connection refused* message.
I removed default configs.
I could not find the reason.

Comment: The second problem is because it looks like you want to `proxy_pass` from the https server to the http server, but you have forgotten to add the `proxy_pass` directive. IDK why you are getting redirected to `localhost` - is prestashop configured that way?

Comment: @RichardSmith, I edit my question.next, could you provide me code of your mentioned, because I test many codes and unfortunately I'm not familiar with nginx

Comment: Remove the try_files. IIRC there's a bug that prevents php-fpm to work correctly.

Comment: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321

Comment: @GerardH.Pille,[this](https://serverfault.com/questions/935486/nginx-pass-my-request-to-default-or-local-address#comment1213682_935486) not worked